# how to make permalinks for dynamically loaded pages

Tags: php, facebook, lightbox, permalinks, dynamically-generated

i am a bit confused about how facebook assigns permalinks to all of the comments,pages,lightbox images and all.for example:your timeline link would be something
like:www.facebook.com/*yourusername* ..which indicates that facebook has a page reserved just for you and the same for its million users..but i guess that page loads dynamically from database .even the comments have a very meaningful link...facebook.com/*yourusername*/commentid/otherparameters/ .when i use a lightbox...i place an anchor tag on the image like lightbox.php?photoid=xxx so that when i click it..it passes the parameter to the page lightbox.php where i retrieve it through GET
        and load it from database..but in this process the url remains the
        same...but when a lightbox opens in facebook..the url in the address
        bar also changes...

this is a very common practice...i may be missing a thing or two here or being dumb...kindly tell  me whats going on here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but in this process the url remains the same...but when a lightbox opens in facebook.. *the url in the address bar also changes...*

If that's what you are actually asking about - your keyword is **HTML5 History API**.

Answer (score 0):

When you are visiting a page like facebook.com/goodfriend good friend is not a directory on facebook facebook just gets goodfriend from url & then it checks database if there be informations for good friend facebook shows that

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The above `.htaccess` will redirect every request to your site that doesn't reach a valid file or folder name, to `index.php`

So now you can call: `http://yoursite.com/some-non-existent-file-or-folders`

And do this in your `index.php`

```
<?php

$token = explode( '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );

if ( $token[1] == 'some-non-existent-file-or-folders )
{
    // do something
}
```